# pyinstaller executable doesn't run in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyinstaller

I looked through other posts and they didn't seem to address the specific issue where *nothing* happens when I try to execute a compiled program.

Not sure if this is an Ubuntu issue or a python issue... Either way I'm very new to both so I'm sure there's some simple answer to this.

I wrote a simple program

```
print("hello")
input("now")
```

and used pyinstaller to compile it into a single file.

pyninstaller --onefile test.py
When I try to run the file by double clicking it in the GUInothing at all happens - no error, no console. I checked properties and it is tagged as executable.

I did an ls first to make sure I was in the correct directory when I tried to run it

```
eric@eric-linux:~/PycharmProjects/helloworld/dist$ ls
mytest  test
```

To run it I entered

```
eric@eric-linux:~/PycharmProjects/helloworld/dist$mytest
```

and got the error:

```
Command 'mytest' not found, did you mean:


command 'mtest' from deb parmetis-test

command 'pytest' from deb python-pytest
```

I also tried compiling with --debug and again got the same result when I ran it.
Is there something separate I have to do in Ubuntu to run an executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it like this: `./mytest`

Bash only looks is the current directory if you specify the relative path to the file.